# How to run a command inside screen such that you can get back to the command's parent shell?

Tags: gnu-screen

What's the best way to run a command inside a screen session such that its parent shell can be accessed?  I want to be able to restart it from within the same screen session.

The best I've managed to come up with is the following:

```
$ cat mr-t.sh 
#!/bin/bash

top
exec /bin/bash
```

and then:

```
screen -e'^\\\' -S top-in-screen ./mr-t.sh
```

Then, if top stops running, I'll at least get a new shell within the same screen session I can work with.  This isn't very elegant, though, and I can't quite convince myself that the signal will reliably be sent to the right process if I hit C-c.  Moreover, C-z doesn't work at all.

I'm using bash 3.2.48 on OSX and 3.2.39 on Linux.  Both are probably patched by OS vendors.

There's nothing special about the `top` command here, of course.

[As an aside, `-e'^\\\'` reassigns the Magick Screen Key from C-a (a bad default if there ever was one) to C-\.]

Comment: What is wrong with just starting `top` from the shell?

Comment: @vonbrand Is that a serious question? Do you really think I'm running top?  More to the point, can you really think of no use cases for wanting to automate starting a long-running program in a manner that makes debugging problems easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this question, I've adopted a different but much more effective solution: **use tmux**.

Start a new named, detached session:

```
$ tmux new -d -s top
```

Send a command to its zeroth window.

```
$ tmux send-keys -t top:0 "top" C-m
```

`C-m` is equivalent to hitting return. Often it's what you want; sometimes you'll want to leave it out.

tmux' command set is well-documented. So it's easy to write far more complicated scripts to drive it.

---

Normally this would be an extremely obnoxious answer, but since it's my question I'll allow myself some leeway, especially since I never really got any of the other methods to work reliably. In contrast, I was able to script tmux correctly the first time I tried to.

Answer (score 7):

Create a `~/.screenrc.top` like so:

```
screen
stuff "top\015"
```

Now run `screen -c ~/.screenrc.top`.  No race condition!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an imperfect solution I found.

```
screen -e'^\\\' -dmS top-in-screen
```

Then you can run:

```
screen -S top-in-screen -p 0 -X stuff 'top^M'
```

(Note that although you'll only see `^M` you should actually type `C-v` followed immediately by `C-m`.)

It's imperfect because (I think) there is a race condition between the first and second invocations of screen.

From http://aperiodic.net/screen/faq#how_to_send_a_command_to_a_window_in_a_running_screen_session_from_the_commandline, which has lots of other good information as well.